# How to see output result when running a test in debugger with protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I want to see output result when running a test in debugger with protractor, in Visual Studio Code.

I have the following parameters:

```
// Name of configuration; appears in the launch configuration drop down menu.
            "name": "Tests",
            // Type of configuration. Possible values: "node", "mono".
            "type": "node",
            // Workspace relative or absolute path to the program.
            "program": "node_modules/*",
            // Automatically stop program after launch.
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            // Command line arguments passed to the program.
            "args": ["Configuration.js", "--resultJsonOutputFile result.json", "--suite=lab"],
            // Workspace relative or absolute path to the working directory of the program being debugged. Default is the current workspace.
            "cwd": "./test/",
            // Workspace relative or absolute path to the runtime executable to be used. Default is the runtime executable on the PATH.
            "runtimeExecutable": "",
            // Optional arguments passed to the runtime executable.
            "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy"],
            // Environment variables passed to the program.
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            // Use JavaScript source maps (if they exist).
            "sourceMaps": false,
            // If JavaScript source maps are enabled, the generated code is expected in this directory.
            "outDir": "output"
```

If I run the command line: `protractor Configuration.js --resultJsonOutputFile output\result.json --suite=smoke`, it works.